# php socket sending XML

Tags: php, xml, sockets, tcp

I have been trying to send this XML block to a device, but no luck.  If I use wireshark it appears to be sending but its like I am missing one little thing, carriage return or something.  I have posted the xml needing to be send and my PHP code.  Any ideas?  Sorry I am new to PHP.

```
<c4soap name="SendToDeviceAsync" async="True">
<param name="iddevice" type="number">14</param>
<param name="data" type="string">
<devicecommand owneridtype="" owneriditem="-1">
<command>SET_LEVEL</command>
<params>
<param>
<name>LEVEL</name>
<value type="INTEGER">
<static>10</static>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</devicecommand>
</param>
</c4soap>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$host = "192.168.0.210";
$port = 5020;

$package[0]  = "<c4soap name=\"SendToDeviceAsync\" async=\"True\">";
$package[1]  = "<param name=\"iddevice\" type=\"number\">14</param>";
$package[2]  = "<param name=\"data\" type=\"string\">";
$package[3]  = "<devicecommand owneridtype=\"\" owneriditem=\"-1\">";
$package[4]  = "<command>SET_LEVEL</command>";
$package[5]  = "<params>";
$package[6]  = "<param>";
$package[7]  = "<name>LEVEL</name>";
$package[8]  = "<value type=\"INTEGER\">";
$package[9]  = "<static>100</static>";
$package[10] = "</value>";
$package[11] = "</param>";
$package[12] = "</params>";
$package[13] = "</devicecommand>";
$package[14] = "</param>";
$package[15] = "</c4soap>";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); 

echo "Attempting to connect to '$host' on port '$port'...<br>\n";

$result = socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);

if ($result === false) {
    $socketError  = socket_last_error($sock);
    $socketString = socket_strerror($socketError);
    $resultString = var_export($result, 1);
    echo "socket_connect() failed.<br>\n",
         "Reason: ($resultString) ", $socketString, "<br>\n";
}

echo "Sending XML...<br>\n";

foreach ($package as $onePackage)
{
    $buffer = $onePackage . "\n";
    $bufferLength = strlen($buffer);
    socket_write($sock, $buffer, $bufferLength);
}

socket_close($sock);

echo "Completed sending!<br>\n";
```

Comment: Does the script on the other end require an XML header? <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: The following information in your question is missing: What is that Device? (Name, Manufacturer, Model). What Service is listening on Port 5020 on that Device? (Name, Specification Documents, Service Software Vendor and Service Software Version). What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? (I removed the dead code form your question)

Comment: I reviewed your code, not only removed the dead code. Please review yourself the changes as well. What comes to mind most prominently where you might run into the problem is that you do not do any error checking when writing to the socket. See http://php.net/socket_write - Next place where errors are easily introduced is creating an XML string "by hand". Instead you can just use an XML library to built such a string, for example [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: Thanks for your responses..... Its a back door to a proprietary control system (control4). I know the connection is good, I do not get errors.  I just wonder if the code is too long to send or if you have to break it up some home.  

Here is a link to the site that broke down the code via wireshark.
https://code.google.com/p/c4touch/wiki/DirectorProtocol

Comment: I was able to get info back using this code below as described in this link(http://www.c4forums.com/viewtopic.php?id=7984), but this code is only using one line of code.  I am trying to send lots of lines to tell my light to turn to 10 percent. 

    <?php
    $fp = fsockopen("192.168.29.10", 5020, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
        $out = "<c4soap name=\"GetVersionInfo\" async=\"False\" />\0";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            echo fgets($fp, 128);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    ?>